# organize a json file from xlsx format

Tags: json

I'm trying to organize a json file structure to be as the following:

[image]

But instead of the 1, 2, 3... I want it to be the Food value, nad under the food value I want the amount of calories.

Any ideas on how to it on an existing file with this format:

```
Food,Calories
"BUTTER,WITH SALT",717
"BUTTER,WHIPPED,W/ SALT",718
"BUTTER OIL,ANHYDROUS",876
"CHEESE,BLUE",353
"CHEESE,BRICK",371
```

Comment: do you need this done in some programming language?

Comment: @Gimhani No. There is only one file that I need it to be done to continue working on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the online tool [here](https://www.csvjson.com/csv2json). You can get the output as
[image]

Hope this is the format what you require.

Comment: This is the format I need indeed. My question is which options did you choose to get what you got?

Comment: I found out how. Thank you!